# lxqt polkit asking for root's password when account is locked

Tags: passwords, authentication

pkexec asks for the root account's password. But the account is locked, it doesn't have a password. Therefore it fails. It's easy to change this behavior in gksu. I don't know if I just suck at using Google but I couldn't find a solution. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work correctly. I wasn't added to the "wheel" group. I fixed it by running:

```
sudo usermod -a -G wheel [user]
```